# cURL GET-params?

Tags: macos, bash, curl, get

i can't download the source code from the site. It displays 'error - please fill in all form data'

the url w/ GET-parameters:

http://bahn.ltur.com/index/search/?mnd=de&lang=de_DE&searchin=DE-SB-VI&trip_mode=trip_simple&from_spar=Hamburg+Dammtor&to_spar=Stuttgart+Hbf&start_datum=01.07.2012&start_time=23%3A49&end_datum=02.07.2012&end_time=23%3A51&SEA_adults=1&SEA_kids1=0&SEA_kids2=0&SEA_adult1=&SEA_adult2=&SEA_adult3=&SEA_adult4=&SEA_adult5=&SEA_kid11=&SEA_kid12=&SEA_kid13=&SEA_kid14=&SEA_kid15=&trainclass_spar=2&x=56&y=5

i tried this via OSX bash: curl -O get_ticket_list.html 
also w/ -L (you get redirected to blah.com/details)
No errors when I open the URL in my Browser.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you click the url you have mentioned in your question then it redirects you to http://bahn.ltur.com/details.

If it asking you to fill the form data, you should be sending in a "POST" request and not "GET" request.

The POST request should have the form data as payload in the request.

See the following to be able to make a POST request:

- https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request
- https://superuser.com/questions/361504/how-to-send-post-with-body-data-headers-andhttp-params-over-the-curl-command

Comment: thank you for the answer. But the Form is using the GET method.
Try bahn.ltur.com - fill in the form and watch the url after submitting the form. for a short time the above GET-url appears and then you get redirected. 
Ill try the POST method...

Comment: i tried curl -dL 'params' url > tix.html
also -F (to specify it as formdata)
no success yet. 
I get the Mainpage (bahn.ltur.com).

Comment: @meeeeeh: GET method has no payload. If it is truly form data then it is POST

Comment: it is form data, but its sent via GET explicitly!
thats the form that sends the data

`<form id="form_spar" method="get" name="form_spar" action="/index/search/">`

if i try to do this i get redirected to the main page. also when i try this with POST data. i also tried to send data via GET&POST to blah/details/  - also no success